# Points A,B,C (fix) and X (variable) such that |AX| + |BX| = |CX|

Tags: triangles, circles, plane-geometry

Let $A,B,C$ (*fix*) points of the plane. Where are points $X$ (*variable*) in the plane with $|AX| + |BX| = |CX|$ ?

It seems $X$ need to lie on the arc under $AB$ of the circumscribed circle of the triangle $ABC$.

How can I prove that?

[image]

Note: There is no Trapezium $AXBC$.

Comment: As you move $X$ close to $A$, this would imply that $|AB|=|AC|$, which isn't true in general.

Comment: @Arthur Do you mean, the positions are not a circle-arc at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the equation for $X$ we can get 
$$4 |A-X|^2 |B-X|^2 = (|C-X|^2 - |A-X|^2 - |B-X|^2)^2$$
which gives you a quartic polynomial in the coordinates of $X$. If this doesn't factor (which in general it won't), the locus of $X$ will not be an arc of a circle, nor any conic section.

Here's a picture of it in the case $A = (0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$, $C = (0,1)$.

[image]

EDIT:  In this particular case, the curve has genus $0$ and therefore has a rational parametrization:

$$ \eqalign{X_1 &= {\frac {64\,{t}^{3}-1024\,{t}^{2}+4096\,t}{9\,{t}^{4}-96\,{t}^
{3}+512\,{t}^{2}-4096\,t+16384}}\cr
X_2 &= {\frac {12\,{t}^{4}-160\,{t}^{3}+512\,{t}^{2}}{9\,{t}^{4}-96\,
{t}^{3}+512\,{t}^{2}-4096\,t+16384}}\cr
 0 \le &t \le 8
}$$

In most cases, it appears the curve has genus one and is an elliptic curve, with no rational parametrization.

Comment: Oh, is it possible to find a  parametric equation of this curve?

Comment: I erase my previous remark ; I can only say that there is a connection with (math.stackexchange.com/q/2236765).

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Ah, parametrization in this particular case. I think, that means parametrization for your shown example with special points A,B,C.   I guess the parametrization for the common case would be much harder ;)

Comment: @Robert Isreal RobertIsrael, please could you check with your CAS or plotter the case `A(0,0); B(1,0); C(0.5, 0.5*sqrt(3))` for an 'Equilateral triangle'. This should give us an arc of a circle....

Comment: @cis Generically, as I said, the curve has genus $1$, so no parametrization.    In the case of the equilateral triangle, the curve is the circle $(x-1/2)^2 + (y-\sqrt{3}/6)^2 = 1/3$, which can be parametrized as $x = {\dfrac {-4\,t\sqrt {3}+3\,{t}^{2}+3}{6\,{t}^{2}+6}}$, $y={\dfrac {\sqrt {3
} \left( 3{t}^{2} -1 \right) }{6\,{t}^{2}+6}}$.  The arc we want is for $1/\sqrt{3} \le t \le 1/\sqrt{3}$.